# Scraping certain attribute - Beautiful Soup Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need help scraping the words "CPCAdvertising.com" within the highlighted span tags (see attached screenshot of the HTML). I am unsure of how to iterate through properly.  Here is what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page_number = 1
flippa_page = requests.get('https://www.flippa.com/search?filter[property_type]=domain&filter[status]=won&filter[sale_method]=auction&page[number]={}&page[size]=250'.format(page_number))
price_list = []
domain_list = []
for i in range(120):
    src = flippa_page.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
    for span_tag in soup.find_all('span'):
        domain_list.append(span_tag.attrs['class'])
    page_number += 1
```

[HTML Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9xvu.png)

Comment: I was only able to parse this with:     soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')
 is lxml working for you?

Comment: By the way: why are you incrementing the `page_number`  but not rescraping the page. And why don't you use `i`?

Comment: lxml did work for me

Comment: i incremented the page number because there are many pages and I am rescraping.  every time page_number goes up the .format changes... I think.  Either way it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using html.parser instead of lxml i could find the span tags:

```
for item in soup.find_all('span'): 
     if (str(item.contents).find('CPCAdvertising.com')) > -1: 
         print(item) 

<span class="Basic___propertyName">CPCAdvertising.com</span>
<span class="Basic___title">CPCAdvertising.com - One Dollar Reserve !!</span>
```

I wasn't able to parse with lxml for some reason, if you can give me a tip on what lxml library your using I can check with it

Comment: Honestly this was only the second webscraper I have ever written.  The first was by explicitly following a YouTube video.  If you look at the comment above it is a little bit simplified version of my code and it worked.  I think you need to import requests for my version to work with lxml, which I did and it ended up working out in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Since your URL doesn't work for me, I'm using a different one from the same website.  Regardless, you can specify the class within the `find_all()` command like so:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

flippa_page = requests.get('https://flippa.com/10339489-e-commerce-sports-and-outdoor')
src = flippa_page.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

for s in soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'ListingList-itemPrice'}):
    # Print out the text within the tag
    print(s.text.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

The words should be in in `span_tag.string`.

Comment: Could you add some more context as to where or what this code looks like?

Comment: Got it.  Thanks!